# Catch hangup while Asterisk AMD is checking

Tags: asterisk, amd

Im having this problem just when i answer the phone and then hangup, but asterisk does not detect the hangup while *AMD* is detecting ?

*Asterisk 11.11*

```
    -- Executing [09XXXXXXXX@appel-sortant:10] NoOp("Local/09XXXXXXXX@appel-sortant-40f9;2", "Next = 0") in new stack
-- Executing [09XXXXXXXX@appel-sortant:11] Set("Local/09XXXXXXXX@appel-sortant-40f9;2", "GLOBAL(NEXT)=0") in new stack
== Setting global variable 'NEXT' to '0'
-- Executing [09XXXXXXXX@appel-sortant:12] Dial("Local/09XXXXXXXX@appel-sortant-40f9;2", "SIP/09XXXXXXXX@forfait-ovh,20,gtr") in new stack
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
-- Called 09XXXXXXXX@forfait-ovh
-- SIP/forfait-ovh-00000000 is ringing
-- SIP/forfait-ovh-00000000 is making progress passing it to Local/09XXXXXXXX@appel-sortant-40f9;2
-- SIP/forfait-ovh-00000000 answered Local/09XXXXXXXX@appel-sortant-40f9;2
> Channel Local/09XXXXXXXX@appel-sortant-40f9;1 was answered.
-- Executing [s@appel-sortant:1] Playback("Local/09XXXXXXXX@appel-sortant-40f9;1", "silence/1") in new stack
-- <Local/09XXXXXXXX@appel-sortant-40f9;1> Playing 'silence/1.gsm' (language 'en')
== Spawn extension (appel-sortant, 09XXXXXXXX, 12) exited non-zero on 'Local/09XXXXXXXX@appel-sortant-40f9;2'
-- Executing [s@appel-sortant:2] AMD("SIP/forfait-ovh-00000000", "") in new stack
-- AMD: SIP/forfait-ovh-00000000 09XXXXXXXX (null) (Fmt: 64)
-- AMD: initialSilence [2500] greeting [1500] afterGreetingSilence [800] totalAnalysisTime [5000] minimumWordLength [100] betweenWordsSilence [50] maximumNumberOfWords [3] silenceThreshold [256] maximumWordLength [5000]
-- AMD: Channel [SIP/forfait-ovh-00000000]. Changed state to STATE_IN_SILENCE
-- AMD: Channel [SIP/forfait-ovh-00000000]. HANGUP
[Aug 31 09:19:35] NOTICE[32712]: pbx_spool.c:349 attempt_thread: Call completed to Local/09XXXXXXXX@appel-sortant
```

**extensions.conf**

```
exten => s,1,Playback(silence/1)
exten => s,n,AMD()
exten => s,n,NoOp(AMDSTATUS = ${AMDSTATUS})
exten => s,n,GotoIf($[${AMDSTATUS}=MACHINE]?appel-sortant-mach,s,1:appel-sortant-humn,s,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem implementing the hangup handler.

[Hangup Handlers](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Hangup+Handlers)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It helped to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Asterisk **DO** detect hangup on called party ALWAYS.

There are no way prevent that.

Check your provider/FXO gate, probably it just not detect hangup.